# plot a function in R using curve

Tags: r

I am trying unsuccessfully to plot the following function in R using curve.
The function is the following:

```r
y ~ GA(mu,sigma), with y >0, mu >0 and sigma >0
fGA <- function(y, mu, sigma) {
  out <- (y^((1/sigma^2)-1))*exp(-y/sigma^2*mu)/(((sigma^2)*mu)^(1/sigma^2))*gamma(1/sigma^2)
  return(out)
}
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) ##mu fixed value
curve(fGA(y, 0, 0.5), -10,10, col="green")
curve(fGA(y, 0, 1), -10,10, col="green")
curve(fGA(y, 0, 2), -10,10, col="green")
curve(fGA(y, 0, 3), -10,10, col="green")

par(mfrow=c(2,2)) ##sigma fixed value
curve(fGA(y, 0, 1), 0,5, col="blue")
curve(fGA(y, 0.5, 1), 0,5, col="blue")
curve(fGA(y, 1, 1), 0,5, col="blue")
curve(fGA(y, 2, 1), 0,5, col="blue")

Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in plot.window(...) : finite values are needed for 'ylim'
```

What possibly is wrong?

Comment: I do not use `curve`, but it seems that first your function `fGA` need to use `x` as an argument. I did that and worked, but `fGA` it is returning `Inf`, `when mu = 0`

Comment: I'm assuming we need your `GA` to know what `y` is? I'm inferring it's something you created using the `GA` *package*. I don't know the package enough to be able to help specifically, but ... have you tried  each of your `fGA(y,0,0.5)` (and others) to make sure that they are returning something usable?

Comment: In `fAG `is `exp(-y/sigma^2*mu)` supposed to be `exp(-y/(sigma^2*mu))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use `curve`, but it seems that first your function `fGA` need to use `x` as an argument, I did that and worked. But `fGA` it is returning `Inf`, when `mu = 0`, so returns an error

### Function

```
fGA <- function(x, mu, sigma) {
  out <- (x^((1/sigma^2)-1))*exp(-x/sigma^2*mu)/(((sigma^2)*mu)^(1/sigma^2))*gamma(1/sigma^2)
  return(out)
}
```

### Example 1 - mu = 0.5 and sigma = 1

```
curve(fGA(x, 0.5, 1), 0,5, col="blue")
```

[image]

### Example 2 - mu = 0 and sigma = .5

```
fGA(-10:10, 0, 0.5)

 [1] -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf  NaN  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf
[19]  Inf  Inf  Inf
```

Comment: It is not necessary to change the function. It is sufficient to write `fGA(x, 0.5, 1)` as the first argument of `curve`.  Alternately, write it with a `y` as shown in the question but add the argument `xname = "y"` to `curve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I realized that the parameter mu has to be > 0. I was trying to plot with mu=0....that´s why it was not working.